# How to assign value to one graph with the other graph who has the same structure in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to implement DQN in tensorflow. Here I have one target network and one training network who have the same structure with each other. In the beginning of every 10000 training steps, I want to load the value from checkpoint to target network and training network, then stop_gradient target network. However, I tried those ways, and none of them worked:

1, Put the two networks in one graph. However, every time I load them, I don't know how to assign the value of training network part to target network part.(They are saved in different values, since one is stop gradient.)

2, Define two graphs using tf.graph() and run two session respectively. However, I can't load the checkpoint of one graph to another, even they have the same structure. After all, they are two different graphs.

So, any one who can give me some advice? Very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The typical approach would be to put everything in one graph, put your two networks in two **name scopes**, and then create tf.assign ops for each variable in one scope to the another and use the tf.group to construct a final "copying" operation. Lets assume that function `create_net()` builds a single network

```
with tf.name_scope('main_network'):
  main_net = create_net()

with tf.name_scope('target_network):
  target_network = create_net()

main_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='main_network') 
target_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, scope='target_network')

# I am assuming get_collection returns variables in the same order, please double
# check this is actually happening

assign_ops = []
for main_var, target_var in zip(main_variables, target_variables):
  assign_ops.append(tf.assign(target_var, tf.identity(main_var)))

copy_operation = tf.group(*assign_ops)
```

Now executing copy_operation in session.run should copy your main network parameters to the target network. The above code should be considered a pseudo code, rather than something you can copy&paste.